# Comparing two decimal numbers upto 3 decimal places

Tags: java

I am getting error in this. Can someone please help me here. I need to compare two decimal numbers upto three decimal numbers

```
public class DecimalComparator{

    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a,double b){
        a=Math.round(a*1000);
        a=a/1000;
        b=Math.round(b*1000);
        b=b/1000;
        System.out.println("the first value is"+a);
        System.out.println("the second value is"+b);
        if(a==b){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You should give some inputs for which the code does not work. But I suspect you need `floor` instead of `round`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a, double b) {

    a = Math.round(a * 1000);
    b = Math.round(b * 1000);
    System.out.println("the first value is" + a);
    System.out.println("the second value is" + b);
    return a == b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be just a matter of defining an epsilon (here, `0.001`), and checking whether the absolute value of the difference between both doubles is smaller than the epsilon:

```
if (Math.abs(a - b) < 0.001) {
    // almost equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer from *@Robby Cornelissen*, you can also use `BigDecimal` with required precision.

```
public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a,double b) {
    BigDecimal da = BigDecimal.valueOf(a).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal db = BigDecimal.valueOf(b).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
 
    return da.equals(db);
}
```

For instance, the following input will return **false**.

```
double x = 10000.0009;
double y = 10000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if by "equal" you meant that two doubles are equal when rounded to two decimal places or when cut to two decimal places. Below is a code snippet that will cover both cases with the use of BigDecimals. If by "equal" you meant first case use `MODE_ROUNDED` variable, if second case use `MODE_FLOOR`.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class DecimalsComparison {

    private static final int DECIMAL_PLACES = 3;
    // if two decimal numbers how are considered equal when rounded
    private static final RoundingMode MODE_ROUNDED = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;
    // if two decimal numbers how are considered equal when cut to two decimal places
    private static final RoundingMode MODE_FLOOR = RoundingMode.FLOOR;

    public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double a,double b){
        System.out.println("the first value is " + a);
        System.out.println("the second value is " + b);
        BigDecimal first = BigDecimal.valueOf(a).setScale(DECIMAL_PLACES, MODE_ROUNDED);
        BigDecimal second = BigDecimal.valueOf(b).setScale(DECIMAL_PLACES, MODE_ROUNDED);

        return first.compareTo(second) == 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Should return true if RoundMode set to HALF_UP, false when set to FLOOR");
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(1.1245, 1.1251));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Should return true if RoundMode set to HALF_UP, false when set to FLOOR");
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(1.1244, 1.1251));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Should return false if RoundMode set to HALF_UP, true when set to FLOOR");
        System.out.println(areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(1.123456, 1.123567));
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Hope that will be useful.